# Importing the text from paragraph elements within a specified division

Tags: import, html

I'd like to import plaintext found within paragraph blocks nested anywhere inside certain div's. Here's a page to try it on:

```
Import @ "https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/european-union-privacy-law-basics/get-to-know-eu-privacy-law?trail_id=learn-privacy-and-data-protection-law"
```

I'm trying to extract strings `text1`, `text2`, etc. from `<p>` blocks whenever nested inside any `<div>`'s of class "unit-content":

```
... <div class="unit-content"> ... <p> text1 </p> ... <p> text2 </p> ... </div> ...
```

Is there an easier way than using the nasty 'XML' functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jsoupLink](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink) for this:

```
Needs["jsoupLink`"]

html = Import[
   "https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/european-union-privacy-law-basics/get-to-know-eu-privacy-law?trail_id=learn-privacy-and-data-protection-law",
   "HTMLDOM"
   ];

texts = #["AllText"] & /@ html["Select", ".unit-content p"];
```